# Optimization for searching for a substring withing list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

**Parameters**

Currently I have a deque like this which is constantly being appended to:

```
choices = [
    ["text approximately 500+ chars long", 1] #second part is a 1 or a 2
]
```

The text the latest email in an email chain and the number determines what to do with it. Any subsequent emails (lower in the chain or above in the chain) should have the same action applied to it.

I am using a deque because I assume that emails that are in the same chain are sent around the same time and thus I can benefit from using the `appendleft` of a deque which is faster than a list.

Currently to achieve my goal I am doing it like this:

```
for choice in choices:
    if current_email in choice[0]: #check for lower level emails
         incident_type = choice[1]
         break
    elif choice[0] in current_email: #check for upper level emails
         incident_type = choice[1]
         break
```

I believe how I am currently searching is O(nkm) for n (the length of the `current_email`) and k (the length of `choices`) and m (the length of the email in k) and thus, makes this a very sub optimal way of doing things. Once choices reaches about 50 then it takes around 5-10 seconds for each full search of choices to complete. Is there a better way of doing this with some other module or method?

Thank you.

Comment: Be [careful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) when posting cross site

Comment: @juvian which site is better for it to be posted to?

Comment: It is [usually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow?rq=1) better to use code review, as stackoverflow is usually for not working code

Comment: What exacly goes into each choice[0] text? If current_email is always an email, you know it will have a @ in it. So of choice[0] has a lot of text unrelated to it, you might want to proprocess it and extract all emails from it for faster lookup

Comment: A whole email. Like body and all. Not just the email address. Same goes for the current email. They are the bodies of an email not email addresses @juvian

Comment: Is current_email an email address or the whole text of an email?

Comment: The whole text of an email @juvian so it’s searching if the email was in a reply chain before.

Comment: If current_email is intended to be a perfect match to one of the choices, you can build a hash out of the choices and your current_email and compare the hashes

Comment: @juvian Again... current email is either one level up in a reply chain from the email in choice[0], one level down in the reply chain, or not in choices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179414/discussion-between-ryan-schaefer-and-juvian).